# Replace Pylint, install newer version from Source, and make it available to syntastic

Tags: software-installation, python, vim, git

I would like to replace the existing `pylint` and `astroid` version on my computer with its current versions which are available via Github and make it available to the vim plugin `syntastic`.

In particular, I use Ubuntu 14.04 and pylint 1.6.4 and astroid 1.4.9 are installed on my computer. I cannot find a PPA to update these two programs to its newest versions. The [website](https://www.pylint.org/#install) of `pylint` says I can install  `pylint` and `astroid` from source using git. The relevant links are:

```
git clone https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint
git clone https://github.com/PyCQA/astroid
```

The new installation should be available to the `vim` plugin `syntastic`.

Can somebody kindly explain me how to achieve these two goals?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Via Pip

Pypi has a [package for Pylint](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pylint).

You can install Pypi packages

- for Python 2 with

  ```
  pip install --user [package]
  ```
- for for Python 3:

  ```
  pip3 install --user [package]
  ```

This will install the package for *current user only*. For a system-wide installation use `sudo` and omit `--user`, e. g. `sudo pip install [package]`.

If you don't have Pip you can install it from Ubuntu's repositories; the package names are `pip` and `pip3` for Python 2 and Python 3 respectively.

### From source

Taken straight from the [section titled “Install”](https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint#install) of the read-me file in the source code repository:

> Pylint requires astroid package (the later the better).
>
> - https://github.com/PyCQA/astroid
>
> Installation should be as simple as:
>
> ```
> python -m pip install astroid
> ```
>
> Pylint requires isort package (the later the better).
>
> - https://github.com/timothycrosley/isort
>
> Installation should be as simple as:
>
> ```
> python -m pip install isort
> ```
>
> If you want to install from a source distribution, extract the tarball<sup>1</sup> and run the following commands:
>
> ```
> python setup.py install
> ```

<sup>1</sup> Obviously, instead of a source code "tarball" you can also use the cloned Git repository.